# pg_restore from dump of table not working

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I created a dump of a Postres table using

`pg_dump -Fc -v --host=host_name --username=user_name --dbname=database_name --table table_name -f E:\file_name.dump`

I am now trying to restore it to a new table and the command just doesn't work, without an error. I have tried running it two ways:

1. `pg_restore -v -Fc -h host_name -U user_name -p 5432 -d database_name -t table_name E:\file_name.dump` returns "pg_restore: implied data-only restore"
2. `pg_restore -v -U user_name --data-only -h host_name -d database_name -t table_name E:\filename.dump` just returns without executing or returning an error

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: #2 works for me.  A) Do you get something like `pg_restore: connecting to database for restore`? B) Is the data in the table?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for responding. A) Yes B) No

Comment: 1) Are you sure that the `pg_dump` was not done with `-a`/`--data-only`? 2) Why are there different file names in the `pg_restore` commands? 3) Does `table_name` exist in the database you are restoring to? Check for names that are of different case. 4) Are you sure you are restoring to correct database? In other words the database you are confirming data in. 5) Try `pg_restore -v -U user_name --data-only -h host_name -t table_name -f table_name.sql  E:\filename.dump` to get plain text restore to file `table_name.sql`.  Then see what is in file?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks again 1) Yes 2) that was a typo 3) I've tried it with and without first creating the table. I would prefer the former as my overall goal is to move the data into a partitioned table 4) the dump and restore are within the same database 5) I did this and got a 1kb file with mainly this text: SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
Is this correct?

Comment: There should be `CREATE TABLE ...` for the table definition and `COPY ...` for the table data.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I get this behavior is if the table name argument differs between the pg_dump and the pg_restore.  You didn't show it differing, but what you did show was almost certainly fake, so that doesn't mean much.

If you try to restore data for a specific table from a dump file which doesn't have data for that specific table, then nothing happens.  pg_restore is not a table renaming tool.  You could use the combination of COPY TO and COPY FROM to duplicate a table under a new name.

Comment: I thought that the dump was just data. Thanks to your and @AdrianKlaver comments, I realize it contains more. My goal was to dump and reload to a partitioned version of the table in the same database. Based on your comments, I recorded my steps and did this by 1) dump table_1 2) rename table_1  to table_1_old 3) create a partitioned version of table_1, called table_1 4) restore the dump to new table_1